# Bash script for regex file renaming

Tags: bash, file, directory, rename

I'm very new to Bash scripts and would like to test it out on the following problem I have. I currently have a lot of files in a directory in the form

```
V3_August_'day'_0_'simulations'.pickle
```

where `'day'` and `'simulations'` represent variables that change for different files. I would like to convert these into the form

```
V3_2012_8_'day+1'_0_'simulations'.pickle
```

What would a script that iterates through these files, renaming them as required be?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think that a bash script would necessarily be the best idea/easy/possible (OK, it would probably be possible, but probably also ugly). Perhaps you should try using Perl.

Comment: Ah ok, for some reason I thought Bash was good for dealing with these things. I wrote something to do it in Python instead.

Comment: Could you also post some sample file names?

Comment: Sample fileNames would be `V3_August_1_0_2000.pickle` or `V3_August_5_0_400.pickle` to `V3_2012_8_2_0_2000.pickle` and `V3_2012_8_6_0_400.pickle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure bash based solution:

```
for x in *.pickle; do
   [[ $x =~ ^([^_]+_[^_]+_)([^_]+)(_.+)$ ]] && mv "$x" \
     "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$((${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1))${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```